# Check the linear dependence or linear independence of the set S = {x , |x|} in C(−1, 1). What about the set in C(0, 1)?

Tags: linear-algebra

I tried forming the set for the required equation and then tried to solve for its equation to see weather it has a trivial or non trivial solution.
But I could form the set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=|x|$.

in $C(-1,1)$: if $a,b \in \mathbb R$ and $0=af+bg$, then

$ax+b|x|=0$ for all $x \in (-1,1)$.

For $x=1/2$ we get $\frac{1}{2}a+\frac{1}{2}b=0$

and $x=-1/2$ gives $-\frac{1}{2}a+\frac{1}{2}b=0$.

Then it is easy ti see that $a=b=0$. Hence $f$ and $g$ are linearly independent in $C(-1,1)$.

In $C(0,1)$ we have $f=g$. Hence $f$ and $g$ are linearly dependent in $C(0,1)$.

Comment: Why did you take this equation "0=af+bg"?

Comment: What are the definitions of " linearly independent /  linearly dependent " ??

Comment: Ok got it......